# Filter WooCommerce orders by user meta value date

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, datefilter

I want to filter the WooCommerce Order List according to user meta data. The products are some kind of subscriptions running for a periode of 12 month.

When a customer orders a product (subscription), a start date of the subscription ist stored in a user meta_key e.g. `international_subscription_start_date`.

Now I want to show all orders, that have `international_subscription_start_date` older than 11 month from now.

I've set up the dropdown successfully:

```
add_action('restrict_manage_posts','add_subscription_filter_to_shop_order_posts_administration');
function add_subscription_filter_to_shop_order_posts_administration(){
    global $post_type;
    if($post_type == 'shop_order'){

    $values = array(
        'Inter. Subs < 1M' => 'international_subscription_start_date_lt_1M', 
        'DE. Subs < 1M'    => 'germany_subscription_start_date_lt_1M',
        'All Subs < 1M'    => 'pvm_all_substriprions_lt_1M',
        'Inter. Subs'      => 'international_subscription_start_date',
        'DE. Subs'         => 'germany_subscription_start_date',
        'All Subs'         => 'pvm_all_substriprions'
    );
    ?>

    <select name="subscriptions_admin_filter">
    <option value=""><?php _e('All Orders', 'pv-mag'); ?></option>
    <?php
        $current_v = isset($_GET['subscriptions_admin_filter']) ? $_GET['subscriptions_admin_filter'] : '';
        foreach ($values as $label => $value) {
            printf
                (
                    '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                    $value,
                    $value == $current_v ? ' selected="selected"' : '',
                    $label
                );
            }
    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Now in the `pre_get_posts` I do the following:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','add_subscriptions_filter_to_shop_order_page');
function add_subscriptions_filter_to_shop_order_page($query){
global $post_type, $pagenow; 

if($pagenow == 'edit.php' && $post_type == 'shop_order'){

    if(isset($_GET['subscriptions_admin_filter']) && $_GET['subscriptions_admin_filter'] != ''){

        $today_minus_11_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-11 month'));
        $today_plus_11_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+11 month'));
        $subs_type = $_GET['subscriptions_admin_filter'];

        switch ($subs_type) {
            case 'international_subscription_start_date_lt_1M':
                $subs_typeA = 'international_subscription_start_date';
                $subs_typeB = 'international_subscription_start_date';
                $date_comp = $today_minus_11_month;
                break;
            case 'germany_subscription_start_date_lt_1M':
                $subs_typeA = 'germany_subscription_start_date';
                $subs_typeB = 'germany_subscription_start_date';
                $date_comp = $today_minus_11_month;
                break;
            case 'pvm_all_substriprions_lt_1M':
                $subs_typeA = 'international_subscription_start_date';
                $subs_typeB = 'germany_subscription_start_date';
                $date_comp = $today_minus_11_month;
                break;
            case 'international_subscription_start_date':
                $subs_typeA = 'international_subscription_start_date';
                $subs_typeB = 'international_subscription_start_date';
                $date_comp = $today_plus_11_month;
                break;
            case 'germany_subscription_start_date':
                $subs_typeA = 'germany_subscription_start_date';
                $subs_typeB = 'germany_subscription_start_date';
                $date_comp = $today_plus_11_month;
                break;
            case 'pvm_all_substriprions':
                $subs_typeA = 'international_subscription_start_date';
                $subs_typeB = 'germany_subscription_start_date';
                $date_comp = $today_plus_11_month;
                break;              
            default:
                break;
        };

        $meta_query = $query->get('meta_query');
        if( empty($meta_query) ) $meta_query = array();

        $meta_query[] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => $subs_typeA,
                'value' => $date_comp,
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => $subs_typeB,
                'value' => $date_comp,
                'compare' => '<=',
                'type' => 'DATE'
            )
        );

        $query->set('meta_query',$meta_query);
        //$query->set('suppress_filters', true);
        //$query->set('post_type', 'shop_order');

    }
}
}
```

When I apply the filter, no order is shown. When I check the query (`var_dump`) the meta_query parameters are passed correctly.

Comment: You've got "substriprions" instead of "subscriptions" in your code; typos?

Comment: Thanks for that, but this is not the problem because I have the same typo in switch statement. The `meta_keys` are correct..